# Voldemort setMaxThreads usage

Tags: java, voldemort

I am learning how to use Voldemort. I can't understand the following method of the class ClientConfig

```
ClientConfig conf = new ClientConfig(); 
StoreClientFactory factory;
StoreClient<String, String> client;

conf.setBootstrapUrls(""tcp://localhost:6666"); 
conf.setMaxThreads(10);  
factory = new SocketStoreClientFactory(conf);
client = factory.getStoreClient("storeName");

Versioned<String> value = client.get("key")
```

My question is, what does `.setMaxThreads()` do exactly? Does it spawn 10 different threads, all of them performing the `.get()` method?

the Voldemort's [javadoc](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/javadoc/all/voldemort/client/ClientConfig.html#setMaxThreads(int)) says just: "Set the maximum number of client threads"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StoreClient will handle separate requests with individual threads, and then when the total number of threads is reached, it becomes blocking.

For example, if you made 5 `client.get("key")` calls 5 threads would be used.